# como realizar una validación para que el usuario no ingrese caracteres o cadenas de texto

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
primero = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
segundo = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: "))
print(primero+segundo)
except:
print('Por favor, procure que lo que ingresó anteriormente sean solo NUMEROS')
```

Este es el codigo, soy nuevo programando en python, agradecería su ayuda

Comment: de la forma en que lo haces está bien, o que es lo que quieres?

Comment: Si cristian, creo que no me expliqué bien. Lo que quería saber es como hacer para que cuando el usuario digite un carácter o cadena, se vuelva a realizar la pregunta de ingrese el primer o segundo número con un mensaje de error

Comment: ok, ahora te doy una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu quieres que el código se vuelva a ejecutar necesitas utilizar el ciclo `while` mas específicamente un `while True`, así:

```py
while True:
    try:
        primero = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
        segundo = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: "))
        print(primero+segundo)
        break #rompemos el ciclo
    except:
        print('Por favor, procure que lo que ingresó anteriormente sean solo NUMEROS')
```

En caso el input sea distinto a un numero, el ciclo se repetirá pidiendo ambos, pero también podemos hacer algo mas interesante, solo pedir el numero que se ingresó mal, para eso nos apoyaremos de una lista para guardar el numero que se ha ingresado.

```py
nums = []
while True:
    try:
        if nums == []: #si no hay numeros significa que no se ha pedido el primero
            primero = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: ")) #pedimos el primero
            nums.append(primero) #agregamos a la lista
        segundo = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: ")) #pedimos el segundo
        nums.append(segundo)#agregamos
        print(primero+segundo) #mostramos
        break #rompemos el ciclo
    except:
        print('Por favor, procure que lo que ingresó anteriormente sean solo NUMEROS')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian, lo entendí perfectamente.

Comment: me alegro que hayas entendido ^_^